# Difficult MySQL Query to Determine Rank For a Parent Based on Aggregated Child Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a single query that can provide me with the rank of a parent based on it's rank among all parents. That rank is determined by the sum of the score field from the parent's children.

Here is the MYSQL table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `score` decimal(6,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I can easily find the rank of a particular child among all children using:

```
SELECT c1.id,c1.name,c1.score,COUNT(c2.id) AS 'rank'
FROM child c1
JOIN child c2
ON c1.score <= c2.score
WHERE c1.id=3;
```

What I can't figure out is how to find the rank of a particular parent among all parents based on the aggregate sum of the score field of each parents' children. The SQL query I'm looking for should return the rank of the parent based on passing in its ID.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If there is no index on parent_id, try adding one there.  It should speed up the joins.
2. I believe the following will get you what you want:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank FROM (
     SELECT SUM(c.score) AS parentScore
       FROM child
     GROUP BY parent_id
        HAVING parentScore <= (SELECT SUM(c.score) FROM child WHERE parent_id = _PARENT_ID)
   ) AS scores
   ```

   The subquery will only execute once because it is not dependent on the enclosing query.  This should minimize trips through the table.  This does not account for ties in scores.  If you want to handle that, you can select distinct scores.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id, p.name, ps.score, count(ps2.score) as 'rank'
from parent p
join (
  select pp.id as 'id', sum(c.score) as 'score'
  from parent pp
  join child c on pp.id = c.parent_id
  group by pp.id
) as 'ps' on p.id = ps.id
join (
  select pp.id as 'id', sum(c.score) as 'score'
  from parent pp
  join child c on pp.id = c.parent_id
  group by pp.id
) as 'ps2' on ps.score <= ps2.score
where p.id = 3;
```

and you may need at the end:

```
group by p.id, p.name, ps.score
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alvin! This query is unfortunately too inefficient for our needs since there can be millions of child rows. I tried simplifying it to the following which removed the second join and instead inserts the score for the target parent but it was still too slow. Any ideas on how we can speed it up further?

`select p.id, p.name, count(ps.popularity) as 'rank'
from parent p
join (
  select pp.id as 'id', sum(c.popularity) as 'popularity'
  from parent pp
  join child c on pp.id = c.parent_id
  group by pp.id
) ps on ps.score >= 98.3835
where p.id = 3;`

Comment: You can try adding indexes to `child.parent_id` and `child.score`. That'll speed things up considerably but if you have millions of rows it may still be too slow. The next step you might want to consider is horizontal partitioning if possible, or moving older records to an "archive" table if they're no longer needed.

Comment: You could also create a permanent table for the parent scores (parent_id, score) and add triggers to the `child` table so that the parent scores table is updated whenever a child's score is added/updated/removed in the `child` table. Once again, an index on `score` would help a lot.